Can I use tRPC and webSocket for creating a real-time card game?
I am going to create a card game using tRPC for getting the data from server to client. But, I was already using xmpp for user presence, multi-chat etc. But, now I want to try it out with the tRPC. Is it a better idea?
Then, I might need to create a timed game / un-timed games based on the game. So, do I need to create a server or something else for WebSockets.
What would be the good idea? Can you guide guys
I have set up the server and client setup using tRPC, and it is working fine for default cases.

Yes, you can use tRPC with websockets. See https://github.com/syhner/next-kickstart
